# Why does the null-conditional operator behave differently for == and .Equals()?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

I had the following code, which works fine:

```
var firstChild = token.First as JProperty;
bool isHref = token.Children().Count() == 1
           && firstChild?.Name == "href";
```

I wanted to make the string comparison case-insensitive, so I changed it to:

```
var firstChild = token.First as JProperty;

bool isHref = token.Children().Count() == 1
           && firstChild?.Name.Equals("href", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Now the compiler is giving me an error:

> Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'

I can fix the error by coalescing to false like

```
bool isHref = token.Children().Count() == 1
         && (firstChild?.Name.Equals("href", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false);
```

But I'm curious why the compiler doesn't like the first null-conditional syntax.

Comment: What if you do `String.Equals(firstChild?.Name, "href", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);` ?

Comment: The reason is that `?.`  will return either `null` or the value, in your case , since there is a method return `bool`, it can only returning `Nullable<bool>` to accommodate `true/false` for actual result or `null` in case `firstChild` is null. Hence the return type of expression is `Nullable<bool>` and since you can't apply `&&` on both, so the error.

Comment: Note that you can use `&` with `bool` and `bool?`.  It will result in a `bool?` though.  `&&` doesn't work because of the short circuiting.  Short circuiting doesn't work because you want a result of `null` if the `bool?` is `null`, but you wouldn't even evaluate the second part if the first part was `false`.

Comment: It boils down to `firstChild` being null. In that case, the entire expression will be null (and not a straight bool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's simplify to the essentials.

```
string x = null, y = null;

// this is null.  b1 is bool?
var b1 = x?.Equals(y); 

// b2 is bool
// this is true, since the operator doesn't require non-null operands
var b2 = x == y;
```

Basically `.Equals()` requires a non-null object to operate on.  That's different than `==`, which is statically bound, not dynamically dispatched.

Comment: Thanks, this is the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

the first expression returns null or bool

if firstChild is null then the return value will be null and it can not be used in an if condition

```
firstChild?.Name.Equals("href", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

will the same as

```
firstChild == null ? null : firstChild.Name.Equals("href", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: That makes sense, but it still doesn't explain why `&& firstChild?.Name == "href"` compiles fine.

Comment: the result of firstChild?.Name is null or an string and then it compares to "href" which result to only a true/false value